# Find out mismatches records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have following two tables `(Tab1 and Tab2)` where I needs to check for mismatch values of `T1Col3` and `T2Col3`.
Link columns of those two tables are `T1Col1, T1Col2` with `T2Col2, T2Col2`

But When I run the following query It doesn't give exact records that I want

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 INNER JOIN Tab2
ON T1Col1 = T2Col1
AND T1Col2 = T2Col2
WHERE T1Col3 <> T2Col3
```

Sample data

Tab1

```
T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3

jkl nnn qoq
efg Aaa wow
efg xxx yoy
abc iii ror
abc fff uou
abc rrr rr3
gdg ppp 123
abc www 234
jkl qqq 336
jkl nnn 888
```

Tab2

```
T2Col1  T2Col2  T2Col3

jkl nnn qoq
efg aaa wow
efg xxx yoy
abc fff uou
ABC iii ror1
abc rrr kok
gdg ppp 789
jkl nnn utu
jkl qqq 336
```

Result

```
T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3  T2Col1  T2Col2  T2Col3

jkl      nnn    888      jkl    nnn     qoq 
abc      iii    ror      abc    iii     ror1
abc      rrr    rr3      abc    rrr     kok
gdg      ppp    123      gdg    ppp     789
jkl      nnn    888      jkl    nnn     utu 
jkl      nnn    qoq      jkl    nnn     utu
```

Unwanted records of above results

```
jkl nnn 888 jkl nnn qoq
jkl nnn qoq jkl nnn utu
```

How can I get rid of highlighted records. I think this happens due to matching duplicate records

Cheers

Shabar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need third and in inner join if you want to remove mismatched third column:

```
SELECT * FROM @Tab1 INNER JOIN @Tab2
ON T1Col1 = T2Col1
AND T1Col2 = T2Col2
AND T1Col3 = T2Col3
```

**Update:**

```
Select * From
(
    Select * From tab1
    Except
    Select * From tab2
)tbl
Inner Join 
(
    Select * From tab2
    Except
    Select * From tab1
)t2
On tbl.T1Col1=t2.T2Col1
And tbl.T1Col2=t2.T2Col2
```

**For MS Access**

```
  Select * From
(
    Select t1.* From Tab1 t1
    Left Join  Tab2 On t1.T1Col1=T2Col1 And  t1.T1Col2=T2Col2 And t1.T1Col3=T2Col3
    Where T2Col1 Is Null And  T2Col2 Is Null And  T2Col3 Is Null
)tbl
Inner Join 
(
    Select t2.* From  Tab2 t2
    Left Join Tab1 t1 On t1.T1Col1=t2.T2Col1 And  t1.T1Col2=t2.T2Col2 And t1.T1Col3=t2.T2Col3
    Where t1.T1Col1 Is Null And  t1.T1Col2 Is Null And  t1.T1Col3 Is Null

)t2
On tbl.T1Col1=t2.T2Col1
And tbl.T1Col2=t2.T2Col2
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Ken. Basically I need to get the missmatch values in `Col3`

Comment: Then your query is working perfectly. It is returning records where third column doesn't matched. Then where is the problem?

Comment: "jkl   nnn 888" is coming two times because you have two record "jkl nnn utu" and "jkl nnn qoq" in tab2 where first two columns are identical but third column is different.

Comment: But in the result set two records are not relevant(I have edited below my question). Others are fine as you mentioned

Comment: My point is ` jkl nnn 888` should come only one time as ` jkl qqq 336` and ` jkl nnn qoq' got matching records in both tables

Comment: Thanks Ken. But I was wondering whether ` Except` work in MS Access. Because sql gives me syntax error